# How can i use kafka producer interceptor in python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, interceptor, kafka-producer-api

we have multiple python worker and we write the data in table through all worker but we have to make sure the last event which we are giving wrote at last unless all worker write the middle data. last data must be enter at last after writing whole data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand how an interceptor helps here, but no, I've not seen interceptors implemented in kafka-python or the Confluent library